# Derogatory term for dragon blooded?

Tags: terminology, exalted

As I understand it, the term 'Anathema' specifically excludes dragon bloods. Is there a derogatory term used, either by mortals or exalts, to refer to dragon bloods?

Comment: Milk drinker...

Comment: Once they realized they were 'Celestial Incarna blooded', my PCs started using 'dragon-blooded' as a derogatory term, a la 'Mudblood'. It's all in the way you say it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anathema is a term used by the Order since the end of the First Age to describe Celestial Exalted to describe the beings that turned the First Age into a tyrannical nightmare. It doesn't apply to the Dragon-blooded, because the Dragon-blooded are/claim to be the good guys and have a Creation-wide propaganda machine.

Solars and Lunars who remember the Usurpation might call Terrestrials usurpers, murderers or scum. There's no general derogatory term in use because there's no propaganda department working with the Solars to cast down the Terrestrials in public perception.

Sidereals are more likely to call them patsies or useful idiots. Probably never to their face though.

Lastly, mortals, are more likely to call them lord or overbearing imperial warmongers, depending on where they are.

Comment: I would love to hear what the gold faction Sidereals call them behind closed doors.

Comment: In the mouth of a Celestial "Terrestrial" can be an insult quite easily.